# .addEventListener won't be added everytime the page loads

Tags: javascript

On loading a page I add an event listener to a form.

```
window.onload=function()
{
  document.getElementById("login").addEventListener("submit", function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
  });
}
```

When I reload the page it sometimes works and sometimes I get the message `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')`.
It's about a 50/50 chance.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: is the element dynamically created?

Comment: The element it refers to gets included via jQuery `$('#loginModalDiv').load(loginModal.html)`

Comment: then that's the problem - sometimes the `.load` takes longer than other times

Comment: How can I make sure, that first the .load is finished and then the listener is added?

Comment: foes `$('#loginModalDiv').load` return a promise - I know some things in jquery do - oh, wait, it takes a callback like in the answer ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on yours (and @Jaromanda X's helpful) comments, perhaps instead use a callback function in the `.load` to bind the event listener?

```
$('#loginModalDiv').load("loginModal.html", function() {
  document.getElementById("login").addEventListener("submit", function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
  });
});
```

Comment: That's exactly how I did it now after I knew that not the `.addListener` is the problem instead the `.laod` is. Thanks!